# Помогите разобраться с трехмерным массивом

Tags: java

Есть функция, у которой параметр трехмерный массив:

```
public void setAnimatedView(int[][][] viewFrames){
    ...
  }
```

Имеется четыре двумерных массива:

```
public static final int[][] KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_FIRST = new int[][]{
            {4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
            {4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
            {4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
    };

    public static final int[][] KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_SECOND = new int[][]{
            {4, 0, 4, 0, 4},
            {0, 4, 0, 4, 0},
            {4, 0, 4, 0, 4}
    };

    public static final int[][] KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_THIRD = new int[][]{
            {0, 4, 0, 4, 0},
            {4, 0, 4, 0, 4},
            {0, 4, 0, 4, 0}
    };

    public static final int[][] DEAD_PLAYER = new int[][]{
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
```

Вот вызов этой функции:

```
super.setAnimatedView({
              {ShapeMatrix.KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_FIRST},
              {ShapeMatrix.KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_SECOND},
              {ShapeMatrix.KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_THIRD},
              {ShapeMatrix.DEAD_PLAYER}});
```

Компилятор не разрешает так делать:
"Array initializer is not allowed here"
Что не так?

Comment: Добавление `int[][][]` перед первой фигурной скобкой должно помочь

Comment: Пробовал, компилятор пишет: Unexpected token

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Корректный код:

```
super.setAnimatedView(new int[][][]{
              ShapeMatrix.KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_FIRST,
              ShapeMatrix.KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_SECOND,
              ShapeMatrix.KILL_PLAYER_ANIMATION_THIRD,
              ShapeMatrix.DEAD_PLAYER});
```